# A theoretical question about matter/antimatter and capacitors

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, antimatter

Let's assume that the experiment is done in a vacuum and there's a circuit as in the attachment. The values of voltage/resistance/capacitance are insignificant.

Assume that the right terminals of capacitors and the wire that connect them are made from antimatter, all else is made from regular matter.

My question is, would the voltage observed on resistor be the same as with the above terminals/wires made from regular matter?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The voltage across the resistor will be the same whether the right half of the circuit is constructed from matter or anti-matter.

During the parts of the period of the sine wave when the **upper** terminal of the supply is at a **positive** potential relative to the lower terminal (as indicated in the diagram) then **conventional** current will flow **clockwise** in the circuit meaning that

- electrons will flow **from** the **left** terminal of the **upper** capacitor **into** the **upper** terminal of the voltage supply and
- electrons will flow **from** the **lower** terminal of the supply through the resistor **into** the **left** terminal of the **lower** capacitor.
- anti-electrons (positive charge) will flow **from** the **right** terminal of the **upper** capacitor **into** the **right** terminal of the lower capacitor.

So we would see both electrons and anti-electrons flowing out of the upper capacitor (with a net-conventional current rightwards) and we would see both electrons and anti-electrons flowing into the lower capacitor (with a net-conventional current leftwards).

All that matters for the resistor voltage is the current running through it and that would be same with matter or anti-matter. The two capacitor terminals interact through the electric field within the capacitor and matter and anti-matter charges produce electric fields the same way.

Answer (score 1):

your circuit would annihilate immediately you can not have matter and antimatter together. The question is how will you get antimatter in the first place?

Comment: I don't agree, you can make two plates of a capacitor as far away as you want, but with increasing distance they need to have bigger size to keep the same capacity. As I mentioned, this mind-experiment is done in vacuum.

Comment: Fine, the circuit is in a vacuum. How do you suspend the anti-matter half of the circuit in the vacuum?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with how to suspend the matter and anti-matter components of the circuit. It is assumed that has been figured out. That said, if you really want a scheme that can do it fine. Construct a matter spaceship which can control its position in space along all three directions. Build the same thing out of antimatter. Install some optical measuring equipment that can mounted on one of the ships so that it can be used to position itself relative to the other. Install each end of this circuit as a payload on each ship.

Comment: Ensure that the propulsion systems are aligned so as not to blow fuel onto the opposite ship as that would cause annihilation. One can also imagine electromagnetic levitation schemes which could be used to levitate one or the other part of the circuit relative to the first.

Comment: @jgerber and  to the ones who think that even in theory this could work: what about where the connection has to be made with matter? wherever they have contact they would annihilate destroying the circuit.

Comment: @annav That's sort of the whole motivation for asking the question I think. A capacitor operates even if you have two plates of matter separated by vacuum. The energy is passed "through" the capacitor via the electric field which is agnostic as to whether it is interacting with matter or anti-matter charges. That is, capacitors can operate with a "vacuum gap". Thus, if you use two capacitor you can "vacuum gap" out one half of a linear circuit from the other half. Thus the question: will such a vacuum gapped circuit still operate if one half of it is made of anti-matter?

Comment: So to address your question: there need not be ANY location where anti-matter makes connection with matter. This is why the circuit can operate in theory.

Comment: what about the anti electrons flying to the real matter plate?

Comment: @jgerber  what of the antimatter plate that has to connect to matter for the circuit to work? it will fast annihilate any contact so no circuit.

Comment: @trula have a look at my answer. No matter or anti-matter cross from one capacitor plate to the other (this is true in an all-matter capacitor as well). Remember that in a capacitor equal charge builds up on both plates creating an electric field in the space between, but there is no matter or anti-matter that crosses from plate to plate, just an electric field.

Comment: @annv Again, there is no location where the "antimatter plate has to connect to matter for the circuit to work". The circuit works without physical contact. have a look at the diagram in the OP. you can draw a closed circle around each of the two halves of the circuit without crossing any blue lines. (hint: the circles will pass through the centers of the capacitors, you split the capacitor in half with vacuum in between.)

Comment: Gerber you are right, sorry for my mistaken post

Comment: @annav sorry, mistagged you in a previous comment